# Add '-ms-transform' and '-webkit-transform' to element using vanilla js

Tags: javascript, css

I am removing jQuery and need to be able to add these css transform attributes to an element using vanilla js:

```css
-ms-transform: scale(1.05); /* IE 9 */
-webkit-transform: scale(1.05); /* Safari */
transform: scale(1.05);
```

Today I have the code changed with jQuery like:

```js
$(".my-class").css({
    '-ms-transform': 'scale(1.05)', /* IE 9 */
    '-webkit-transform': 'scale(1.05)', /* Safari */
    'transform': 'scale(1.05)',
})
```

The problem is to do something like:

```js
$element.style.-ms-transform = 'scale(1.05)'
```

But this does not work

Comment: Damn, I will just not use it :D  .... it seems most major browser supports the `transform`

Comment: Were you every able to resolve this issue? If so, did my answer below help you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try doing it like this:

```js
$element.style["-ms-transform"] = 'scale(1.05)'
```

Remember that you can access objects like arrays with strings. [W3Schools page on Objects](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_objects.asp)